# Contents of build method rebuilt without any setState calls

Tags: caching, garbage-collection, dart, flutter

My app has a lot of API calls and image downloads, that's why i'm using [Cache Manager package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_cache_manager).

I noticed a lot of content is re downloaded and my app sends API requests without me doing anything but scrolling the screen.

I started checking and the `build()` method **does** gets rebuilt any time, but it has nothing to do with any `setState()` calls whatsoever!

Is there a chance the garbage collector or cache issues have something to do with that?
I get a lot of debug prints like `Background concurrent copying GC freed 368(32KB) AllocSpace objects, 18(1632KB) LOS objects, 56% free, 1202KB/2MB, paused 25.610ms total 107.349ms`.

If not what can cause it?

Comment: We need a minimalistic working code that reproduce the problem

Comment: Please provide an example of the code that isn't working as you expect.

Comment: It is probably because you are scrolling content and it is getting in and out of the visible screen.. We can only make assumptions because you did not provide us any information about your actual setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i deleted the question but thought about it and un-deleted it to answer with the solution if anyone else will ever encounter such a behavior:

**It is very weird but seems like the problem was having my widget as a child of a `RefreshIndicator` widget.**

I'm sure i didn't even scroll to the position it should indeed activate my refresh method, but scrolling any direction too far (even horizontally while my refresh indicator was a regular vertical one) activated it for some reason.

Sorry for not providing any example while asking the question, the app was too complicated and i didn't even know what is relevant and what's not...

**Edit:**
Now it's just a real mystery, i added a `print('Refresh')` line to my `onRefresh` method, and it never got printed, even when the widget got rebuilt!

If anyone have some kind of explanation i would really like to hear it.

Comment: Flutter can call build whenever it wants to.  Move expensive API calls out of build methods and into StatefulWidget lifecycles

Comment: Same issue i am getting with refresh indicator